# Django Model self referencing M2M field

Tags: django, m2m

I'm trying to get a Django model to automatically construct a typical __str__(self) value for itself (in the model definition), but based on 3 ManyToMany Fields. Unlike when using basic field types (as in the first two models), this doesn't appear to work for M2M fields (see the third model).
The model migrates fine, but causes errors when being referenced in the admin.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

```
class Party(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField("Party", max_length=150)  
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

    class Meta:
         ordering = ('name',)

class ValCharBehav(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField("Value / Character / Behaviour", max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class ValCharBehavWithPeople(models.Model):
    vcb=models.ManyToManyField(ValCharBehav, verbose_name="Value / Character / Behvaiour")
    bywhom=models.ManyToManyField(Party, verbose_name="By Whom", blank=True, related_name="valCharByWhomReverseAccessor")
    towhom=models.ManyToManyField(Party, verbose_name="To Whom", blank=True, related_name="valCharToWhomReverseAccessor")

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
         return self.vcb.name+": by: "+self.bywhom.name+", to: "+self.towhom.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_vcb_name(self):
    return ' | '.join(self.vcb.filter(
        name__isnull=False
    ).values_list('name', flat=True))

def get_bywhom_name(self):
    return ' | '.join(self.bywhom.filter(
        name__isnull=False
    ).values_list('name', flat=True))

def get_towhom_name(self):
    return ' | '.join(self.towhom.filter(
        name__isnull=False
    ).values_list('name', flat=True))

def __str__(self):           
     return self.get_vcb_name()+": by: "+self.get_bywhom_name()+", to: "+self.get_towhom_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer a slightly more terse version of @ykh’s answer:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s, by %s, to %s' % [ 
        ' | '.join(x.values_list('name', flat=True))
        for x in (self.vcb, self.bywhom, self.towhom) ]
```